# Pandas Series.Shift truncates last value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a series of 35 values with the index 0 to 34.  Its set like that (0 to 34 vs. 1 to 25) to be inline with other series I am using.  However, when I try to use the np.npv function it treats the first value as of today, not one year out.  So I need to push it out one year but having trouble using either series.shift or dataframe.shift.  if I use

```
myseries.shift(1)
```

the value at 0 becomes NaN (which I assume is easy to switch to zero) but it stops at value 34 (the old 33) and truncates the last value (the old 34).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to shift the index by one, you can do that directly without touching the `pd.Series`:

```
In [148]: df = pd.DataFrame([5, 10, 15, 12])

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
    0
0   5
1  10
2  15
3  12

In [150]: df.index += 1

In [151]: df
Out[151]:
    0
1   5
2  10
3  15
4  12
```